Find extreme points of $2x^3-12x+3y^2+6xy$ on restriction

Let's consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y):=2x^3-12x+3y^2+6xy$. Find the global maximum and global minimum on $D:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\geq 0,y\geq0,x+y\leq 1\}$.


My approach:
First, by solving $Df(x,y)=(0,0)$ we easily find a local minimum at $(2,-2)$ with $f(2,-2)=-20$. There are no other extreme points on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (there exists a saddle point at $(-1,1)$ which we ignore).
The existence of global extreme points on $D$ is guaranteed by compactness of $D$ and continuity of $f$. It suffices if we only look at the boundary of $D$ because possible extreme points in the interior have already been covered by the condition $Df(x,y)=(0,0)$; note that $(2,-2)\notin D$.
Next,
a.) $f(0,0)=0$.
b.) If $x=0$ and $0<y\leq 1$, then $0<f(x,y)\leq 3$.
c.) If $0<x\leq 1$ and $y=0$, then $f(x,0)$ is monotonically decreasing and $-10\leq f(x,0)<0$.
d.) If $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ and $x+y<1$, then this condition defines the interior of $D$.
e.) If $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ and $x+y=1$, then we can apply the method of Lagrange multipliers which yields
\begin{align*}
&6x^2-12+6y=\lambda\\
&6y+6x=\lambda\\
&x+y=1\\
&\implies x^2-x-2=0\implies x_1=-1\land x_2=2, \text{ where } x_1,x_2\notin D
\end{align*}
So this condition doesn't deliver any possible global extreme points.
Condition b.) delivers the global maximum, namely $f(0,1)=3$ and c.) delivers the global minimum on $D$, namely $f(1,0)=-10$.

I am not quite sure if I can prove it like this because in the sample solution there are different cases where the Lagrange multipiers are used. But I don't think that this is necessary, isn't it?

Everything seems fine to me. Actually in your last case, e.), you don't need to use the Lagrange multipliers method. The constrain is of the form $x+y=1:\Rightarrow:y=1-x$, with $x\in(0,1)$, so you only have to study the function $$g(x):=f(x,1-x)=2x^3-3x^2-12x+3$$ on $(0,1)$, which is strictly decreasing. So the global maximum on $D$ is $f(0,1)=3$ and the global minimum is $f(1,0)=-10$, as you have correctly stated.
